# Why we use partial wave analysis for scattering amplitude?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, angular-momentum, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Why we use partial wave analysis for scattering amplitude?
We can do it by Born approximation also

Comment: Greetings! If you have a new question, please ask a new question rather than editing an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read scattering theory 2 weeks back but I'll try to answer to test myself.

Born Approximation and Partial Wave Analysis are two very different kind of approaches to solve the scattering problems.

While studying Born approximation you must have encountered a specific line that " **let's assume the potential is a localized one".**
This statement has two significances one is mathematical and other is intuitive.

What do we mean by 'localized' ? That means the potential go weak quickly at distance from the scattering center and thus the total wavefunction after scattering does not deter much from the incident one.

The intuitive significance is that now you know born approximation is for weak potentials. the mathematical advantage/significance is that you get to approximate the wavefunction in the Green Function equal to the incident one.

This is crucial thing in order to prove the validity of the Born Approximation as well.

In proving the validity of Born Approximation you take the scattering part of total wavefunction to be a small one because the potential is a weak one.

So $$\psi_{total}= \psi + \psi_{scattering}$$
$$\psi_{total} \approx \psi$$
Thus $|\psi|>> |\psi_{scattering}|$.
$$ |\psi_{scattering}|^2 <<|\psi|^2 = 1$$
**$$|\psi_{scattering}|^2 << 1 $$** **This is the validity condition for the Born Approximation. So Born Approximation is for weak potentials.**

But what about the potentials that are significant thus have an effect that should be considered ?

We do comparison of the wave function of our incident particle in presence of no potential and in presence of potential a.k.a. our scattering center.

This scattering potential causes the phase shifts in the wavefunction and thus helps us to calculate the scattering amplitude.

This is why we have to choose which one to use in order to calculate the scattering amplitude in different conditions. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer could be improved. I would not call localized potentials weak. Their influence becomes negligible at adequately large distances, yet the interaction they describe must not be "weak" itself, in any inherent sense. Also, writing $\psi \gg \psi'$ is pretty abusive notation, there is no standard ordering relation on complex functions or Hilbert space vectors.

Comment: I meant they are localized so they go weak quickly at distance from the scattering center.

Comment: Very good. That's why I encourage you to improve your answer by being a bit more precise about these things.

Comment: Thanks for the input.